# Using \ContinuedFloat creating errors with table captions

Tags: tables, captions, subfloats

I have a figure in my document that has 10 subfigures, and overflows onto two pages. I have used two `figure` environments and `\ContinuedFloat` to get the correct lettering between subfloats. The problem now is that `\caption` no longer works in `table` environments. Here is an example of the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\caption{cat}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{cat}
\label{cat}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\ref{cat}

\begin{figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put a caption for the figure too to get an anchor there. Otherwise, the anchor from previous `\caption` will be taken (here it is a table) and throw an error.

```
.
.
.
\ref{cat}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{Figure here}
\end{figure}
```

to get things right.

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{cat}\label{cat}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \hline
4 & 5 & 6 \\ \hline
7 & 8 & 9 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\ref{cat}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\caption{Figure here}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\caption{continued here}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please note that `center` environment is not suitable for use with `figure` and `table` as it leaves extra (un-necessary) vertical space.

Comment: Thats awesome thank you, I didn't have a caption in the first figure environment in my document as I only needed it under the second. But that makes sense ill leave  blank one. cheers

Comment: @Stephen You are welcome. Glad it helped. Have a nice day.

Comment: You forgot to tell that `center` shouldn't be used in `table` or `figure`.